# How to limit nodes retrievable via Service module in Drupal?

Tags: web-services, drupal, drupal-7

I've put together a simple web service in my Drupal website, using the apposite module (Services). Now, i can check the endpoint "node" and "retrieve" inside the module, for it to expose content of nodes of my website, but i don't really want to include EVERY node in it. I'd rather want to expose only a couple of selected contents.

To explain myself better: i need to expose the content of my 'disclaimer' nodes to a mobile app, but activating the node-retrieve endpoint means all nodes are exposed and i don't really want it.

So, there's a way to limit which node must be exposed via the Service module endpoint node-retrieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [services_entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_entity) module, and use `pagesize` query parameter to return a specific number of nodes.

Example: return 15 nodes of type `page`

> /api/node?pagesize=15&parameters[type]=page

Comment: yes, but it is not yet what i'm searching for. With node retrieve i can do a Get request someurl/node/34 to retrieve content of node number 34, you know. What i want is to expose only node 34, for example. So that if i do a get someurl/node/35 i get no result, for i do want to expose node 34 but not all the others. Maybe it is not *so* necessary, for actually nodes are exposed throught the normal website, but i feel more comfortable with my web service exposing only what i do willingly want to expose. (I fear about attacks made possible to website in this way)

Comment: I am not sure what do you want to achieve!

Comment: The module Service allow you to do a get call to an url http://www,yoursite.foo/node/34 that replies with the page content. The call can be called as http://www,yoursite.foo/node/XX with XX the number of your node. EVERY node. I want it to work for node number 34, but not for all the others.